# MySQL Nested Union Alternative

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get a union of subqueries in MySQL. This alone is pretty simple.

```
(subquery A)
 union
(subquery B limit 15)
 union
(subquery C limit 15)
```

But it's important that the union of B and C total 30 records. If B has fewer than 15, I need C to fill the remainder. So I try this:

```
(subquery B limit 15)
 union
(subquery C)
 limit 30
```

And that gets me what I need. Once I add A back in, resulting in a nested union, MySQL gives a syntax error.

```
(subquery A)
 union
(
 (subquery B limit 15)
  union
 (subquery C)
  limit 30
)
```

Is there another way to get the same end result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like

```
(select x from a)
union 
(select * from 
 (
  (select y from b limit 15)
    union 
  (select z from c)
  limit 30
 ) as k
)
```